# Графика в C#. Работа с PictureBox

Tags: c#, графика, изображения

Суть проблемы такова: у меня есть массив объектов. Каждый объект имеет числовое значение и компонент `PictureBox`(создается динамически для каждого объекта). Каждый `PictureBox` имеет картинку на фоне, которая задается в конструкторе

```
this.Card.Image = Image.FromFile("Card.png");
```

При нажатии на `PictureBox` я хочу, чтобы на нем отображалась другая картинка, а поверх нее изображалось чсиловое значение, соответсвующее этому объекту.
У меня есть код:

```
public void OpenCard()    
{    
    this.Card.Image = Image.FromFile("CardOpen.png");    
    this.Card.BackColor = Color.Transparent;    
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(this.Card.Handle);    
    g.DrawString(this.Value.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 35), Brushes.Blue, new Point(0, 20));    
    g.Dispose(); 
}
```

Однако при нажатии картинка меняется, но изображения числа нет. Никто не может помочь мне решить эту проблему?

Comment: Попробуйте 

    Graphics g = this.Card.CreateGraphics();

Comment: Попробовал - результат аналогичный

Comment: Может, всё дело в `this.Card.Image`? Может, стоило эту картинку как BackGround поставить?

Comment: Не знаю. Поверх текущей картинки числовое значение отображается, а поверх новой - нет. Через BackGround пробовал - не получилось)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не могу понять, зачем устанавливать на картинку свойство Image и BackColor, тем более в значение Transparent? Ну да ладно, а ответ очень прост*
Ты прорисовываешь число в неправильном месте, так как сначала прорисовывается число, после окончания твоей процедуры начинает обновляться интерфейс по установленным свойствам и твоя графика просто затирается.
Вариантов много, вот один из них, для твоего случая:

---

```
 Image myTempImage = Image.FromFile("CardOpen.png");
 Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(myTempImage);
 g.DrawString(this.Value.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 35), Brushes.Blue, new Point(0, 20));    
 g.Dispose();
 this.Card.Image = myTempImage;
```

Надеюсь я заслужил + :)

Comment: спасибо. теперь все заработало!